# Как работают кодировки?

Tags: java, кодировка, unicode

У меня есть следующий код:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{

                PrintWriter aa = new PrintWriter("qwer.txt", "UTF-8");
                aa.write('й');
                aa.flush();
                FileInputStream j = new FileInputStream("qwer.txt");
                System.out.println(j.read());
                System.out.println(j.read());
                InputStreamReader g = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("qwer.txt"), "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(g.read());

        }
}
```

Я создаю символьный поток с кодировкой `UTF-8` и записываю в файл символ `й`.

Согласно следующей таблице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

значения символа `й` в кодировке `UTF-8` равно `53433` или `208` и `185` если по байтам. Метод `j.read()` байтового потока, вызванный два раза подряд, выдаёт вполне логичные две строчки `208` и `185`. После чего я создаю символьный поток ввода для того, чтобы прочитать сразу один символ. Создаю его в той же кодировке. Я ожидаю, что метод `g.read()` вернёт число `53433`, но к моему удивлению он возвращает `1081`. Причём я попробовал все возможные кодировки и если методы `j.read()` всегда изменяет своё значение согласно данной таблице, то вот `g.read()` каждый раз возвращает `1081`. Почему ?

Comment: Кириллица в UTF-8 занимает 2 байта. И, наверное, лучше явно передавать кодировку в конструктор InputStreamReader, чтобы использовалась не системная (для windows это будет cp1251, а она однобайтовая)

Comment: InputStreamReader выполняет автоматическое декодирование байтов в символы, и 1081 — это код символа `й` в таблице символов юникода, а не байты из кодировки (то есть смотреть в эту таблицу кодировок вообще не надо)

Comment: (вообще, столбик «dec» в этой таблице какой-то вредный, так как он неявно подразумевает big endian и создаёт дополнительную путаницу)

Comment: @andreymal да, всё верно 1081 - это код, код в кодировке `UTF-16BE` и `UTF-32BE`, а в кодировке `UTF-8` этот код равен `53433`. Разве не так ?

Comment: @VanechikSpace ещё раз, это **не код в кодировке**, это код из таблицы символов юникода, с кодировками UTF-16BE и UTF-32BE этот код не имеет никакой связи, это всего лишь случайное совпадение

Comment: @VanechikSpace Рекомендую прочитать https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#introduction-to-unicode. Вступление рассказывает как что называется и чем отличаются codepoint, character, glyph, code unit. У вас вопрос возник, так как вы тут путаете понятия codepoint и code unit.